# how do I increment an integer variable I passed into a function in Scala?

Tags: scala, parameter-passing, immutability

I declared a variable outside the function like this:

```
var s: Int = 0
```

passed it such as this:

```
def function(s: Int): Boolean={

   s += 1

   return true

}
```

but the error lines wont go away under the "s +=" for the life of me. I tried everything. I am new to Scala btw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Scala call by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790050/can-scala-call-by-reference)

Comment: why would you want to increment the value in a function? Just return the new value. You are reassigning the value you passed in.

Comment: i am doing something else with the value. this is just a small example of what my problem was.

Comment: You cannot do this, you are really calling `s = s + 1` so you are simply reassigning your local pointer to a new variable.

Comment: @JL all you can do in *this particular case* is to wrap int into say MutableInt container, that has operation increment and then pass it to function and invoke that method. You might think that this is a lot of overhead and indeed it is: you're going straight against language concepts.

Comment: return it, you can use a tuple.

Comment: J L, you might consider reviewing [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala) for why `val` (and immutability in general) is preferable to `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I will repeat my words of caution: **solution below is both obscure and inefficient**, if it possible try to stick with `val`ues.

```
implicit class MutableInt(var value: Int) {
  def inc() = { value+=1 } 
}

def function(s: MutableInt): Boolean={
   s.inc() // parentheses here to denote that method has side effects
   return true
}
```

And here is code in action:

```
scala> val x: MutableInt = 0 
x: MutableInt = MutableInt@44e70ff

scala> function(x)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> x.value
res1: Int = 1
```

Comment: @JL I hope you're not going to seriously use this "solution" for anything, and I don't think that was om-nom-nom's intention.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want continuously increasing integers, you can use a Stream.

```scala
val numberStream = Stream.iterate(0)(_ + 1).iterator
```

That creates an iterator over a never-ending stream of number, starting at zero.  Then, to get the next number, call

```
val number: Int = numberStream.next
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also just started using Scala this was my work around.

```
var s: Int = 0
```

---

```
def function(s: Int): Boolean={

   var newS = s
   newS = newS + 1 
   s = newS
   return true

}
```

From What i read you are not passing the same "s" into your function as is in the rest of the code. I am sure there is a even better way but this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

A `var` is a name that refers to a reference which might be changed. When you call a function, you pass the reference itself, and a new name gets bound to it.

So, to change what reference the name points to, you need a reference to whatever contains the name. If it is an object, that's easy enough. If it is a local variable, then it is not possible.

See also call by reference, though I don't think this question is a true duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to increment a variable starting with 3

val nextId = { var i = 3; () => { i += 1;  i } }

then invoke it:

nextId()

Comment: This doesn't actually address the question (which was asked, and answered, 4 years ago).