# Define function that flips its arguments

Tags: scala, arguments, syntax-error, swap, function-definition

I am new to Scala language and I was trying to define a basic function that flips its arguments, I defined it like this:

`var flipArguments = ((a: Any, b: Any) => Any ) => ((b: Any, a: Any) => Any)`

but I am getting a compiling error that highlights the second arrow with the message

```
';' or newline expected
```

and I am not understanding where I am making a syntax error.

Comment: First you are mixing the type definition with the function body. Second, please do not use `var` for a function. Third, in this case it would be better to write a **method**, as it can be _generic_ instead of using `Any`. Finally, here is the code you want: `def flip[A, B](a: A, b: B): (B, A) = (b, a)`.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you mean by flip.

### Flip as in "change the value of two variables"

If you mean that

```
var a = 1
var b = 2
flip(a, b)
```

should result in `a` being 2 and `b` being 1, as one could do with references in C++, then this is not possible in Scala. Here is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4790094/7685624).

### Flip as in "return a tuple of the arguments in reversed order"

This is already answered perfectly in [Pedro's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56836986/7685624).
If this is what you want, you probably should use generics though, as mentioned by Luis in the comments.

### Flip as in "turn a functions arguments around"

Given the signature you tried to write, your attempt looks to me as if you were trying to write a function which gets a function `f` and returns a new function, same as `f`, but with reversed argument order.

You can write such a function like this:

```
def flipAny(f: (Any, Any) => Any): (Any, Any) => Any =
  (a, b) => f(b, a)
```

and then call it on a function like this:

```
def stringify(a: Any, b: Any): String =
  s"a: ${a.toString}, b: ${b.toString}"

println(stringify(1,2))           // prints a: 1, b: 2
println(flipAny(stringify)(1,2))  // prints a: 2, b: 1
```

We can do better however, because using `Any` everywhere removes valuable type information.

What happens if we try to use the string result of `stringify`?

```
println(stringify(1,2).length)            // prints 10
//println(flipAny(stringify)(1,2).length) // doesn't compile
```

The second line doesn't compile because `flipAny` returns a function returning `Any`, not `String`.

Here is another definition using generics:

```
def flip[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): (B, A) => C =
  (a, b) => f(b, a)
```

This is much better. We are getting a function from `A` and `B` to `C` and returning a function from `B` and `A` to `C`. This retains the type information:

```
println(stringify(1,2))              // prints a: 1, b: 2
println(flip(stringify)(1,2))        // prints a: 2, b: 1
println(stringify(1,2).length)       // prints 10
println(flip(stringify)(1,2).length) // prints 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
def flipArguments(a:Any, b: Any): Any = (b, a)
```